# Messed up in Eclipse after viewing a sample project

Tags: android, eclipse

I imported a sample  4.0.3 project and after deleting it from the Project Explorer list every thing is lost, now there are none of the projects that I was working before in Package Explorer??
Moreover now on importing these old project For Example name "On" are coming with the name "OnActivity" but still not able to run.
Else in workspace every file is ok, I tried to CLEAN but still no effect.
[image: screen shot of the new project I tried to create]

I'm new to devlopment kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recover the source code from your workspace in the `Windows` file browser. If all attempts to recover fail, you can just create the projects from existing (recovered) code.

And what project are you trying to run? If `APIDemo` or `QAActivity`, the log shows you why you can't run them.

And instead of using the `Play button` (start) to launch, use the dropdown triangle and select the project to run, else the `XML` will be run (obviously that won't work).

Furthermore, make sure `Eclipse` knows it's a `Android Project` you're trying to run.